# Civi membership receipt emails - how to turn on/off per membership?

Tags: civimember, receipts, recurring-contributions

We have many automated renew memberships with automated recurring contribution profiles. Civi has a great system of sending automated payment receipts for each of these automated contributions through its system workflow message, "Membership receipt (online)".

We can edit those messages, and with a bit of SMARTY decision making, we can change their content quite substantially from one membership type to another.

But is it possible to actually turn off auto receipts completely for one membership type and leave them on for others?

And if so, how?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Membership online receipts are delivered based on which Contribution Page someone completes. So if you used multiple such pages, you could turn off 'send receipt' for some of them.

If they all have to come in from the same page for some reason then alternatively you may be able to run a post-process hook and change the the civicrm_contribution.contribution_page_id value, or since this is memberships, it may relate to the value in civicrm_membership_block.entity_id value (guessing a bit here but the membership block is set to be on specific contribution pages by this value, and that may therefore link to the Contribution page ID and hence whether a receipt gets sent or not)

Comment: Aha! This is perfect Pete, thanks for your thoughts. Such a simple solution - I'd completely forgotten that individual payment pages allow you to choose whether or not they'll send a receipt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do that with the standard scheduled reminders in CiviCRM. A possible solution could be to not use the scheduled reminders but use CiviRules to configure the sending of the automated renew emails? That would give you the possibility to only do it for certain membership types, or use specific templates for specific membership types.

What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said: Drupal 7.52 and Civicrm 4.6.24. CiviRules is a very good idea. I'll look into that and report back. However, we'd still need to somehow turn off the standard payment receipt emails and I'm not at all sure how to do that.